# I can't get requests.session() to work properly

Tags: python, python-requests

I've just discovered the session method for requests and figured I'd play around with it a bit, but with several websites I've tried, I cannot get it to work properly. One site that I'd particularly like to get to work is the NYTimes for which I have a subscription. Here's what I've got:

```
login_page='https://myaccount.nytimes.com/auth/login'
payload={'email':'my@email.com','password':'my_password'}

#I'm after information on this page which is my saved articles after logged in
saved_articles='https://www.nytimes.com/saved'

with requests.Session() as session:
   session.get(login_page) #GET before POST
   post = session.post(login_page, data=payload)
   r = session.get(saved_articles)
```

I'm not having any luck, though. `post.status_code` is `200`, but if I put in a wrong password it's the same. When looking at `r.text` it's clear to see I'm not "logged-in". Here's some things I've learned:

On the login page, I've read that I need to search for the `<form action=...>` argument to find the exact link that POSTs, but there is none. I'm assuming the `login_page` link above is correct.

The login input element is easy and just named 'email' but the password is hidden at first, named 'hiddenPassword' until the email is submitted at which point the password input becomes 'password'. I've experimented with both with no success. I've tried utilizing a few different things to POST that I've read in other questions, but no luck.

Can anybody be so kind as to point me in the correct direction? I'm an amateur pythonista, but I'm really wanting to learn.

Comment: It's very common for major websites to be inoperable without Javascript. I'm not saying that is for certain your problem, but have you verified that you can successfully pass the login screen using, e.g, `curl`? Until you've got that working, this isn't really a Python problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you help clarify what you mean by can I get past the login screen using curl? Thanks.